# Difference of finite difference solution between two timesteps

Tags: fortran, differential-equations

I have a solution to a discretized differential equation given by

```
f(i)
```

where `i` is a spatial index. How can I find the difference between the solution at each adjacent time step? To be more clear:

The solution is defined by an array

```
real,dimension(0:10) :: f
```

I discretize the differential equation and solve it by stepping forward in time.  If the time index is `k`, a portion of my code is

```
do k=1,25
   do i = 1,10
      f(i) = f(i+1)+f(i-1)+f(i)
   end do
end do
```

I can print the solution, `f(i)` at each time step `k` by the following code

```
print*, "print f(i) for k=, k
print "(//(5(5x,e22.14)))", f
```

How can I find the difference between the solution at each adjacent time step?  That is, time steps `k+1`,`k`.  I will store this value in a new array `g`, which has a dimension given by

```
real,dimension(0:10) :: g
```

So I am trying to find

```
!g(i)=abs(f(i;k+1)-f(i;k))...Not correct code.
```

How can I do this?  What is the way to implement this code?  I am not sure how  to do this using if /then statements or whatever code would need be needed to do this.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, in explicit time integration methods or iterative methods, you have to save the last time-step last solution, the current time-step solution and possibly even some more.

So you have

```
  real,dimension(0:10) :: f0, f
```

where `f0` is the previous  value

You iterate your Jacobi or Gauss-Seidel discretization:

```
f = f0

do k=1,25

   do i = 1,9
      f(i) = f(i+1)+f(i-1)+f(i)
   end do

   max_diff = maxval(abs(f-f0))

   if (diff small enough) exit

   f0 = f 
end do
```

If you have a time-evolving problem like a heat equation:

```
f = f0

do k=1,25

   do i = 1,9
      f(i) = f0(i) + dt * viscosity * (f0(i+1)+f0(i-1)+f0(i))
   end do

   max_diff = maxval(abs(f-f0))

   f0 = f 
end do
```

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks a lot.  In regards to the time-evolving problem, I have one question. How come you used maxval(abs(f-f0))?  and not just abs(f-f0)?  I am not sure I entirely understand what maxval is doing.

Comment: What I did is to compute maximal value of all differences in the entire grid. If you want an array (grid) with the differences, then you just use `abs(f-f0)`. Also note that I  selected the simplest way how to write it, not necesarilly the fastest one. You can also use a do loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have a spatial mesh at each point time.  Transient problems require that you calculate the value at the end of a time step based on the values at the start:

```
f(i, j+1) = f(i, j) + f(dot)(i, j)*dt  // Euler integration where f(dot) = df/dt derivative
```

i is the spatial index; j is the temporal one.

Comment: No, If I had an array of 100000 time steps times all my 100 000 000 cells, I would have real troubles where to store it.

Comment: I would not be so silly as to store every time step in memory.  I don't see the need.   I can see writing history to disk, but no need to keep it all in memory.

Comment: Vladimir F I do not understand your comments, sorry..  Duffymo:  How does this help?  f(i,j+1) does not make sense since that would be an array size error .  My array for f is only defined by its spatial index.   I get a solution at each discrete time step. I Sorry if I am misunderstanding what you mean.

Comment: @duffymo I do not see how this addressed my question  You see how I discretized the equation in my question, how could this implementation work in the code?  Thanks!

Comment: Typical matricies I see from finite difference and finite element methods are highly banded and sparse.  Maybe you need to think harder about how you generate and store your matricies.

Comment: You used a central difference formula; the idea is the same.